# Is there a "set -e" for a DOS batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In bash "set -e" at the beginning of the script instructs bash to fail the whole script on first failure of any command inside.

How do I do the same for a Windows batch script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly but you can add the following to every line which has something to execute.

```
|| goto :error
```

And then define error, which stops the script.

```
:error
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: +1, but there is an even simpler solution. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13863374/1012053).

Answer (score 19):

Tuim's solution works, but it can be made even simpler.

The ERRORLEVEL is already set, so there is no need to GOTO a label that sets the ERRORLEVEL.

You can simply use

```
yourCommand || exit /b
```

Note that exit /b will only exit the current subroutine if you are in the middle of a CALL. Your script will have to exit each CALL, layer by layer, until it reaches the root of the script. That will happen automatically as long as you also put the test after each CALL statement

```
call :label || exit /b
```

It is possible to force a batch script to exit immediately from any CALL depth. See [How can I exit a batch file from within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534911/how-can-i-exit-a-batch-file-from-within-a-function/10537432#10537432) for more info. Be sure to read both answers. The accepted answer has a couple of potentially serious drawbacks.