# Throw an exception within an batch file

Tags: batch-file, deployment, teamcity, build-automation

I have created a couple of batch files to aid in the automation process of my deployments. 
They work great, but I want to be able to have the file bomb out if a problem is found, obviously reporting the problem.

I am planning on integrating the scripts into a TeamCity build, so if one of the scripts fails I need to stop the deployment process.

One easy way is to make the script running a manual process, but that defeats the objective.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: what's wrong with `exit`  command?

Comment: This just jumps out the batch file, I need to report an error msg, and if possible a code.

Comment: I just went and looked it up, and you can pass in an int value for the exit code.
If you want to write that as the answer @npocmaka I'll mark it as the answer. 
Thanks,

Comment: But `exit /b <number>` doesn't stop the batch file anymore, it only returns from one call level. It exits the batch file only in the case when it's already at the top level

Comment: Try a look at [SO: Exit batch script from inside a function:](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3227796/463115) and for batch exception handling at [DosTips: 
Exception Handling...](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6497) This stuff is a bit advanced

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18471376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 @code
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ProcessError    
        @code
        exit /b 0    
        :ProcessError
        @codeprocess error
        exit /b 1
```