# Batch - Call script inside script with vertical bar ("|") causes error

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

If a script which should get exited in subroutines without closing the terminal when calling `EXIT 1`. There for I use [this](https://superuser.com/a/203672/505763) `if` which calls the script again.

This worked fine until I now discovered some issue with a quoted vertical bar as a parameter `"!"`. I get an error stating that the command is misspelled.

Here is the part of the script that fails:

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    IF "%selfWrapped%"=="" (
        REM this is necessary so that we can use "exit" to terminate the batch file,
        REM and all subroutines, but not the original cmd.exe
        SET selfWrapped=true
        %ComSpec% /s /c ""%~0" %*"
        GOTO :EOF
    ) 

    echo %*

    ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Call:

```
test.cmd "hello world" "|"
```

Expected Output:

```
"hello world" "|"
```

I checked the the value of `%*` inside the `IF` but for it seems totally legitimate to use a vertical bar as well as any other quoted string.

So...

1. Why does the script fails?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Works ok if you just run the bat directly or use call: `"%~0" %*` or `CALL "%~0" %*`

Comment: Have you tried this: `"%ComSpec%" /S /C "%~0" %*`?

Comment: @Squashman, as mentioned in the remarks, the new `cmd` instance is needed to be able to terminate the batch script and all its sub-routines using `exit`, so the current instance does not become quit...

Comment: What about this: `"%ComSpec%" /S /C ^^^""%~0" %*^^^"`, or even `"%ComSpec%" /S /C ^^^""%~0" %`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the necessity to append the parameter to your `%ComSpec% /s /c ""%~0" %*"` at all.

As you already use a variable (`selfWrapped`) to detect, if the wrapper call is necessary, you could also put your arguments into a variable.

`set args=%*`

Then you can simply use `!args!` in your child instance.

```
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

    IF "%selfWrapped%"=="" (
        @REM this is necessary so that we can use "exit" to terminate the batch file,
        @REM and all subroutines, but not the original cmd.exe
        SET "selfWrapped=true"

        SET ^"args=%*"
        "%ComSpec%" /s /c ""%~f0""
        GOTO :EOF
    )

:Main

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ECHO(!args!
EXIT /B 0
```

Now the only problem left, is the `set args=%*`.
If you can't control the content, then there is no way to access `%*` in a simple safe way.
Think of this batch invokations

> myBatch.bat "abc|"
>   myBatch.bat abc^|
>   myBatch.bat abc^|--"|"

But you could use [How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200316/463115)
or [Get arguments without temporary file](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8574)

Btw. You could spare your child process, you can also exit from a function
Look at [Exit batch script from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3227796/463115)

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with some of the description in the link.
See `exit /?` accurate help description.

- `exit` exits the interpreter.
- `exit 1` exits the interpreter with exitcode 1.
- `exit /b` has similar behavior as `goto :eof`  which exits
  the script or called label. *Errorlevel* is not reset so allows
  *errorlevel* from the previous command to be accessable after
  exit of the script or the called label.
- `exit /b 1` exits the script or the called label with *errorlevel 1*.

If you oddly use `exit /b` at a CMD prompt, it is going to exit the interpreter.

---

**Main code:**

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET args=%*
    SET "self=%~f0"

    IF "%selfWrapped%"=="" (
        @REM this is necessary so that we can use "exit" to terminate the batch file,
        @REM and all subroutines, but not the original cmd.exe
        SET "selfWrapped=true"

        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        ECHO !ComSpec! /s /c ""!self!" !args!"
        "!ComSpec!" /s /c ""!self!" !args!"
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    ECHO(%*
EXIT /B 0
```

Both use of `GOTO :EOF` and `EXIT /B 0` will exit the script.
`ENDLOCAL` is implied at exit of the script.
Explicit use of `ENDLOCAL` is for when you want to end the
current local scope and continue the script. As always, being
explicit all the time is a choice.

Setting `%*` to `args` keeps the double quoting paired.
Quoting i.e. `set "args=%*"` can cause issue sometimes
though not using quotes allow code injection i.e.
arguments `"arg1" ^& del *.*`. If the `del *.*` is not going
to execute at the `set` line, then it will probably happen
at the `ComSpec` line. For this example, I chose not quote.
So, it is a choice.

You are using disabled expansion at start of the script. That
saves the `!` arguments which is good. Before you execute
`ComSpec` though, enable delayed expansion and use `!args!`
which is now protected from the interpreter now not seeing `|`
or any other special character which may throw an error.

Your script fails as the `|` argument is exposed.

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c ""test.cmd" "  | ""
```

The above is echoed evaluation of the `ComSpec` line with
setting `@ECHO ON`. Notice the pairing of quotes
i.e. `""`, `" "` and `""`. Notice the extra spacing inserted
around the `|` character as the interpreter does not consider
it as part of a quoted string.

Compared to updated code changes of echoed evaluation...:

```
"!ComSpec!" /s /c ""!self!" !args!"
```

The string between the quotes remain intact. No extra spacing
inserted into the string. The echoed evalution looks good and
executes good.

***Disclaimer:***

*Expressing the workings of CMD is like walking a tight rope.
Just when you think you know, fall off the rope you go.*

Comment: It would be interesting to see what Jeb and Dbenham have to say about the question. They are pretty knowledgeable about the parsing rules.

Comment: Nice, but regard that delayed expansion only helps in the parent `cmd` instance but not in the child one! Anyway, there is still room for improvement: 1. You are expanding `%`-variables while delayed expansion is enabled, which can cause trouble particularly with `!` characters; change all `%` expansions to `!` ones to be safe (like `!ComSpec!`; then do `set "self=%~0F"` before enabling delayed expansion and use `!self!` instead of `%~f0` later). 2. Put `!ComSpec!` in between `""` to allow custom system directories containing white-spaces. 3. Use the safe `echo` syntax `echo(%*`.

Comment: 4. I would escape the outer quotes in the child `cmd` instantiation, like this: `"!ComSpec!" /S /C ^""!self!" !args!^"`, to avoid syntax errors when `cmd` attempts to remove outer quotes. 5. I would remove the quotes at `set args=%*`, because under normal circumstances, arguments are already quoted correctly (e. g., when doing drag-and-drop, arguments with white-spaces and special characters are already quoted, so another pair of quotes exposes special characters to `cmd` unintentionally). In case of unbalanced quotes, both the unquoted and the quoted assignmend variants can fail anyway.

Comment: @aschipf. **1.** Done. **2.** Done. **3.** Done. **4.** CMD will strip the outer quotes anyway as `/s` enforces it and old CMD behavior ensures it, if with using `/c` or `/k` rule #2 applies in `cmd /?`. I just do not see how using `^"` on the arguments outer quotes is a safer option. If it passed to the script OK initially, then delayed expansion should protect it until it executes `ComSpec` and gets passed again. Need further convincing before appling it. **5.** Done. **#.** Thankyou for your advice with keeping me on the tight rope.

Comment: The purpose of **4.** is to present quotes to `cmd` which it will strip, in order to avoid stripping of needed quotes (like `"program.exe" "argument"` becoming `program.exe" "argument`)... You're welcome!

Comment: @aschipfl **5.** drag-and-drop does only quote arguments with white spaces, but not for special characters like in `Cat&dog.txt`

Comment: @jeb, thanks for correcting, I had it wrong in mind and didn't check! So the final question is, what is better: `set args=%*` or `set "args=%*"`? I my opinion, it doesn't matter, because dragging-and-dropping `cat&dog.txt` and `cat & dog.txt` results in different quoting, hence one of the `&`s becomes exposed to `cmd` in any case; or did I miss anything?

Comment: @jeb, `cmd`'s auto-completion feature automatically quotes paths containing the special characters listed at the end of `cmd /?` plus `%`, that is what I had in mind...

Comment: @aschipfl 1. `set args=%*` works in more cases than `set "args=%*"`, as `cat&dog.txt` can't fetched with `%*` at all, ithe `&dog.txt is` not part of `%*`, see also [SO:Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192427/463115). Your second comment is a good point, that is obviously useful behaviour

Answer (score 1):

One correction to above answers. 
Yes, `ENDLOCAL` is implied at the end of the script, but there's a catch.

I've found that with nested scripts, if you don't `ENDLOCAL` before you `EXIT /B 1` you will not get your return code of `1` at the next level out script.

If you only ever `EXIT /B 0`, then this will not matter as the default return code is `0`.